# Sample project throwing NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper

Tags: spring-batch

I have implemented the project as per https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

But i am getting :

Error creating bean with name 'batchConfigurer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper

I am new to spring-batch
Can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

The following is working as expected:

```
$>git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing.git
$>cd gs-batch-processing/complete
$>./mvnw clean install
$>./mvnw spring-boot:run
```

The output is the following:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

2019-05-30 12:23:12.642  INFO 90644 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on localhost with PID 90644 (/private/tmp/gs-batch-processing/complete/target/classes started by mbenhassine in /private/tmp/gs-batch-processing/complete)
2019-05-30 12:23:12.646  INFO 90644 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-05-30 12:23:13.333  INFO 90644 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-05-30 12:23:13.338  WARN 90644 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2019-05-30 12:23:13.683  INFO 90644 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (feature not supported)
2019-05-30 12:23:13.687  INFO 90644 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-05-30 12:23:14.091  INFO 90644 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL
2019-05-30 12:23:14.277  INFO 90644 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2019-05-30 12:23:14.437  INFO 90644 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Started Application in 2.114 seconds (JVM running for 5.2)
2019-05-30 12:23:14.438  INFO 90644 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2019-05-30 12:23:14.503  INFO 90644 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}]
2019-05-30 12:23:14.530  INFO 90644 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
2019-05-30 12:23:14.590  INFO 90644 --- [           main] hello.PersonItemProcessor                : Converting (firstName: Jill, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JILL, lastName: DOE)
2019-05-30 12:23:14.590  INFO 90644 --- [           main] hello.PersonItemProcessor                : Converting (firstName: Joe, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JOE, lastName: DOE)
2019-05-30 12:23:14.590  INFO 90644 --- [           main] hello.PersonItemProcessor                : Converting (firstName: Justin, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JUSTIN, lastName: DOE)
2019-05-30 12:23:14.590  INFO 90644 --- [           main] hello.PersonItemProcessor                : Converting (firstName: Jane, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JANE, lastName: DOE)
2019-05-30 12:23:14.590  INFO 90644 --- [           main] hello.PersonItemProcessor                : Converting (firstName: John, lastName: Doe) into (firstName: JOHN, lastName: DOE)
2019-05-30 12:23:14.604  INFO 90644 --- [           main] hello.JobCompletionNotificationListener  : !!! JOB FINISHED! Time to verify the results
2019-05-30 12:23:14.607  INFO 90644 --- [           main] hello.JobCompletionNotificationListener  : Found <firstName: JILL, lastName: DOE> in the database.
2019-05-30 12:23:14.607  INFO 90644 --- [           main] hello.JobCompletionNotificationListener  : Found <firstName: JOE, lastName: DOE> in the database.
2019-05-30 12:23:14.607  INFO 90644 --- [           main] hello.JobCompletionNotificationListener  : Found <firstName: JUSTIN, lastName: DOE> in the database.
2019-05-30 12:23:14.607  INFO 90644 --- [           main] hello.JobCompletionNotificationListener  : Found <firstName: JANE, lastName: DOE> in the database.
2019-05-30 12:23:14.607  INFO 90644 --- [           main] hello.JobCompletionNotificationListener  : Found <firstName: JOHN, lastName: DOE> in the database.
2019-05-30 12:23:14.610  INFO 90644 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=importUserJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
```

As you can see, there is no `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: I am still getting the same after cloning as well . What could be the reason .Same dependencies everything is same

Answer (score 0):

2 jars were corrupted , jackson-data bind and log4 .

While mvn clean install error was `(invalid LOC header bad signature)` in the logs but build was getting successfull hence i missed the logs.

i had to  delete the folder from .m2 and then run `mvn clean install` this resolved the issue